# java.io.IOException in MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to use MapReduce to get the max value and min value for each year in a txt file. the contents in the file look like this:

```
1979 23 23 2 43 24 25 26 26 26 26 25 26
1980 26 27 28 28 28 30 31 31 31 30 30 30
1981 31 32 32 32 33 34 35 36 36 34 34 34
1984 39 38 39 39 39 41 42 43 40 39 38 38
1985 38 39 39 39 39 41 41 41 00 40 39 39
```

The first column represents years.
I want MapReduce to give me a final output like this:

```
1979 2, 26
1980 26, 31
...
```

so I write the code in Java like this:

```
public class MaxValue_MinValue {

    public static class E_Mappter extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line = value.toString();
            String[] elements = line.split("\\s");
            Text outputKey = new Text(elements[0]);
            for(int i = 1; i<elements.length;i++) {
                context.write(outputKey, new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(elements[i])));
            }
        }
    }

    public static class E_Reducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable, Text, Text> {
        public void reduce(Text inKey,Iterable<IntWritable> inValues, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int maxTemp = 0;
            int minTemp = 0;
            for(IntWritable ele : inValues) {
                if (ele.get() > maxTemp) {
                    maxTemp = ele.get();
                }    
                if (ele.get() < minTemp) {
                    minTemp = ele.get();
                }
            }
            context.write(inKey, new Text("Max is " + maxTemp + ", Min is " + minTemp));
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf,"Max value, min value for each year");
        job.setJarByClass(MaxValue_MinValue.class);
        job.setMapperClass(E_Mappter.class);
        job.setReducerClass(E_Reducer.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(E_Reducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1);
    }

}
```

but when I run it, I got below error messages:

```
hadoop@steven81-HP:/usr/local/hadoop277$ ./bin/hadoop jar ./myApp/MinValue_MaxValue.jar /user/hadoop/input/Electrical__Consumption.txt /user/hadoop/output7
19/04/10 16:59:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
19/04/10 16:59:21 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
19/04/10 16:59:21 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
19/04/10 16:59:22 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
19/04/10 16:59:22 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
19/04/10 16:59:22 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local1076320101_0001
19/04/10 16:59:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
19/04/10 16:59:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local1076320101_0001
19/04/10 16:59:23 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
19/04/10 16:59:23 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
19/04/10 16:59:23 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
19/04/10 16:59:23 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
19/04/10 16:59:23 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1076320101_0001_m_000000_0
19/04/10 16:59:23 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
19/04/10 16:59:23 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
19/04/10 16:59:23 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/input/Electrical__Consumption.txt:0+204
19/04/10 16:59:23 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
19/04/10 16:59:23 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
19/04/10 16:59:23 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
19/04/10 16:59:23 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
19/04/10 16:59:23 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
19/04/10 16:59:23 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
19/04/10 16:59:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
19/04/10 16:59:24 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
19/04/10 16:59:24 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1076320101_0001 running in uber mode : false
19/04/10 16:59:24 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
19/04/10 16:59:24 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1076320101_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1077)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
    at test.map.reduce.MaxValue_MinValue$E_Mappter.map(MaxValue_MinValue.java:23)
    at test.map.reduce.MaxValue_MinValue$E_Mappter.map(MaxValue_MinValue.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19/04/10 16:59:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1076320101_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
19/04/10 16:59:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

I was confused by this error "Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable" because the map's output is (Text, IntWritable) and the input for the reduce is also (Text, IntWritable), so I don't know why, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Combiner must be able to accept data from the Mapper, and must output data that can be used as input for the Reducer. In your case, the Combiner output type is `<Text, Text>`, but the Reducer input type is `<Text, IntWritable>` and so they don't match.

You don't actually need MapReduce for this problem, because you have all the data for each year available on each line, and you don't need to compare between lines.

```
String line = value.toString();
String[] elements = line.split("\\s");
Text year = new Text(elements[0]);
int maxTemp = INTEGER.MIN_VALUE;
int minTemp = INTEGER.MAX_VALUE;
int temp;
for(int i = 1; i<elements.length;i++) {
    temp = Integer.parseInt(elements[i])
    if (temp < minTemp) {
        minTemp = temp;
    } else if (temp > maxTemp) {
        maxTemp = temp;
    }
}

System.out.println("For year " + year + ", the minimum temperature was " + minTemp + " and the maximum temperature was " + maxTemp);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also find if I comment out the code "job.setCombinerClass(E_Reducer.class);" the program will work even though it would not produce correct result (actually there is a bug for comparison), but I still don't know why till saw your explanation here, thank you so much.